# Reading a text file and perform the conditional statements manually

Tags: c#

I have a text file - a template file, which has all the imports, parameters, constants, class name, methods etc.
I need to read it manually and wherever needed, need to replace the corresponding value from excel file.
In this within the method we have if, else statements too.
Where i need to read the statement, if the condition statisfies, enter the loop and proceed further. The corresponding else part needs to be ignored.
Any idea\suggestions on how this can be done? the if else needs to be executed manually.

Sample code Example:

```
if(0==0) {
    if(1==0) {
        value=0;
    } else {
        value=1;
    }
    return value;
} else {
    return 0;
}
```

So in this case, if the first if part returns, I need to skip the last else. Im counting the condition satisfaction by counting the braces.

Comment: Are you asking how to write an interpreter?

Comment: Ever tried using a scripting language like 'Lua' ?

Comment: ok, ya an interpreter. But if Iam able to import some lib and can use, that also will do. No, i havent tried. Will check about that now

Comment: Suggesting a solution would be much easire if you can provide sample input text and excel file and then explain what you need to replace.

Comment: There is a library for C# called NLua, try it out, it's lightweight and works perfectly!!

Answer (score 1):

For those purpose i like to use `IronPython`. It is a language based on the `Dynamic Language Runtime` (DLR). This should give you a nice tool to do what you want. More information can be found here: [Home of IronPython](http://www.ironpython.net)

To complete the answer, also IronRuby should be a solution for you. But with this i have no experiance...

**EDIT**

Even with the newest .net framework and `Roslyn` you have a big amount of possibilities to do what you want. Just read a litte bit about c#-scripting with roslyn.

Comment: Thank you so much. I will look into it

Comment: We have implemented our complete business logic with IronPython, so it may fit into your needs :)

Comment: woho...i already started reading about it. If on any doubts, will check with you. Thank you

Comment: I'm always happy if i could help. And even more if the DLR find a new user :)

Answer (score 1):

If IronPython/Ruby aren't desirable options, you may want to look at [`Roslyn`](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn).  If that's not an option there's always the [`System.Reflection.Emit`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.emit%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) namespace.